# Hide columns where all values are 0 with DT::datatable

Tags: r, dataframe, dt

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      Z = structure(
        1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D",
                        "E"), class = "factor"
      ), H1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1 = c(178L,
                                            182L, 197L, 177L, 163L), H2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2 = c(85L,
                                                                                                        77L, 66L, 68L, 86L), X3 = c(320L, 344L, 332L, 311L, 322L)
    ), class = c("tbl_df",
                 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-5L), .Names = c("Z",
                                                                         "H1", "X1", "H2", "X2", "X3")
  )
```

Is there a way to tell `DT::datable` to hide the columns that only have zeros? In this case `H1`, and `H2`

I can do this:

```
library(DT)
df1 %>% 
  datatable(rownames = F,
            extensions = 'ColVis', options = list(
              dom = 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
              colVis = list(exclude = c(0), activate = 'mouseover')
            ))
```

and then manually hide those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df1` is a `data.frame` you could do:

```
df1[, colSums(df1 != 0) > 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug that is fixed for versions 1.9.8+; please update your installation.

```
library(data.table) #1.9.8+
setDT(df1)
DT[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) if any(as.integer(x)) x)]
#    Z  X1 X2  X3
# 1: A 178 85 320
# 2: B 182 77 344
# 3: C 197 66 332
# 4: D 177 68 311
# 5: E 163 86 322
```

edit: just realized this is not a `data.table` question specifically. but this *does* work, so i'll leave it here.